# How to select a relationship and a sum of values in doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have following entity:

```
    InventoryStack:
     - product: Product
     - series: Series
     - quantity: integer
```

Now I want to sum all items on that list grouped by product and series.

The most obvious way would be like this:

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i');
    $qb->andwhere('i.product IN :products')->setParameter('products', $products);

    $qb->select('i.product as product');
    $qb->addSelect('i.series as series');
    $qb->addSelect('sum(i.quantity) as quantity');

    $qb->groupBy('IDENTITY(i.product)');
    $qb->addGroupBy('IDENTITY(i.series)');
```

but it ends up with exception: `Cannot group by undefined identification or result variable.`

Then I tried to use a join (not ideal since I had indexes that were supposed to help this and now I cannot use them):

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i');
    $qb->andwhere('i.product IN :products')->setParameter('products', $products);

    $qb->select('p as product');
    $qb->addSelect('s as series');
    $qb->addSelect('sum(i.quantity) as quantity');

    $qb->join('i.product', 'p');
    $qb->join('i.series', 's');

    $qb->groupBy('p.id');
    $qb->addGroupBy('s.id');
```

But that ended with exception: `Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.`

My last attempt was to use the join from the other side:

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i');
    $qb->andwhere('i.product IN :products')->setParameter('products', $products);

    $qb->select('p as product');
    $qb->addSelect('s as series');
    $qb->addSelect('sum(i.quantity) as quantity');

    $qb->join(ProductInterface::class, 'p', 'with', 'p = i.product');
    $qb->join(SeriesInterface::class, 's', 'with', 's = i.series');

    $qb->groupBy('p.id');
    $qb->addGroupBy('s.id');
```

the sql looked correct,
but now doctrine completely botched hydration, instead of expected

```
    [
      [$product, $series, $quantity],
      [$product, $series, $quantity],
      [$product, $series, $quantity],
    ]
```

returning

```
    [
      [$product],
      [$series, $quantity],
      [$series, $quantity],
      [$product],
      [$series, $quantity],
    ]
```

Am I missing something?
What is the correct way to request a set of relationships and aggregates from grouped result in doctrine?